# Рекурсивный обход. Правильно ли я понимаю код?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

По условию [задачи](https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion#rekursivnye-obhody) у нас есть компания, в которой структура персонала представлена в виде объекта. Нужно составить функцию для получения суммы всех затрат.

```js
let company = {
  sales: [{
    name: 'John',
    salary: 1000
  }, {
    name: 'Alice',
    salary: 600
  }],

  development: {
    sites: [{
      name: 'Peter',
      salary: 2000
    }, {
      name: 'Alex',
      salary: 1800
    }],

    internals: [{
      name: 'Jack',
      salary: 1300
    }]
  }
};
```

Решение

```js
let company = { // тот же самый объект, сжатый для краткости
  sales: [{name: 'John', salary: 1000}, {name: 'Alice', salary: 600 }],
  development: {
    sites: [{name: 'Peter', salary: 2000}, {name: 'Alex', salary: 1800 }],
    internals: [{name: 'Jack', salary: 1300}]
  }
};

// Функция для подсчёта суммы зарплат
function sumSalaries(department) {
  if (Array.isArray(department)) { // случай (1)
    return department.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.salary, 0); // сумма элементов массива
  } else { // случай (2)
    let sum = 0;
    for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
      sum += sumSalaries(subdep); // рекурсивно вызывается для подотделов, суммируя результаты
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

alert(sumSalaries(company)); // 6700
```

Как я понимаю, данное решение работает так:

1) Т.к company не массив, то `Array.isArray() == false`, тогда переходим во вторую ветвь, где `Object.values()` возвращает:

**one**- `[{name: "John", salary: 1000}, {name: "Alice", salary: 600}]`

**two**- `{object}`

2)Потом в цикле:

`sum += SumSalaries(subdep);` где subdep = **one**

3)Т.к. значение **one** - это массив, то `Array.isArray() == true` и reduce суммирует зарплату в значении **one**. В итоге SumSalaries(**one**) вернёт 1600 и sum = 1600 (сохраняем данное значение в стеке)

4)Потом в цикле:

`sum += SumSalaries(subdep);` где subdep = **two**

5)Т.к. **two** не массив, во второй ветви `Object.values()` возвращает:

**three**- `[{name: "Peter", salary: 2000}, {name: "Alex", salary: 1800}]`,

**four**- `[{name: "Jack", salary: 2000}, {name: "Alex", salary: 1300}]`,

6) Потом в цикле:

`sum += SumSalaries(three);`

7)Т.к. `Array.isArray(three) == true`, то SumSalaries(three) возвращает 3800 и sum = 3800 (сохраняем значение в стеке)

8)Потом в цикле:
`sum += SumSalaries(four);`

9)Т.к. `Array.isArray(four) == true`, то SumSalaries(four) возвращает 1300 и sum = 1300

10) sum += 3800 (sum == 5100)

11)  sum += 1600 (sum == 6700)

Comment: Да!) P.s. `console.log( JSON.stringify( company ).match(/(?<="salary":)\d+/g).reduce( (a,b) => +a + +b ) );` ))

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME , спасибо!

Comment: Что такое **one** и **two**? У вас нет таких ключей в объекте.

Comment: @Stepan поправил. Надеюсь так лучше.

Comment: Нет, так еще хуже :) Где у вас в коде переменная **one**? У вас идет итерация по ключам объекта `company`, следовательно `subdep==='sales'` на перво итерации и `subdep==='development'` на второй итерации при "первой" рекурсии.

Comment: @Stepan , сначала я просто выделил one, two, three, four жирным и записал туда sales, development, sites, internals соответственно, для того чтобы не переписывать целые строки значений, которые хранятся в этих свойствах и, для того, чтобы более детально в них разобраться, потому что мне трудновато даётся эта тема для понимания (они есть только у меня на черновике). Видимо, мне было нужно указать на это явно, я не продумал это. :)